# pyqt5 привязка клавиши к событию

Tags: python, pyqt5, клавиатура

Знаю про переопределения метода `keyPressEvent` в классе виджета, но проблема в том, что  `keyPressEvent` вызывается только в случае, если в данный момент виджет активен. Так вот мне нужно, чтобы метод

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
        self.start_and_stop()
```

вызывался когда активно окно, но когда я переопределяю этот метод в MainWindow, то метод не вызывается, если активен любой другой виджет в окне. Как привязать этот метод к событию нажатия пробела во всем окне включая все его виджеты?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стал заморачиваться и просто использовал бы другую библиотеку. Например, это можно сделать с помощью модуля [`keyboard`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#api) - `pip install keyboard`

**Импортируем библиотеку:** `import keyboard`

**В классе виджета привязываем к нажатию кнопки вызов функции:**

`keyboard.on_press_key(57, keyPressEvent)`

**57 - код пробела (можно указать 'space'), keyPressEvent - вызываемая функция*

Comment: заморачиваться - это когда без необходимости начинаешь подключать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: решение имеет место быть, но я забыл сказать, что мне нужно обязательно использовать именно qt.

Comment: @СашаЯночкин, в таком случае, прошу дополнить вопрос кодом, демонстрирующим проблему. Я бы запустил у себя, посмотреть, что можно сделать